# Adding a random effect for a categorical variable

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I'm following up on [this great answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228814/140365). Given the structure of my data (below), is it possible to add a random-effect for `H` (*a cluster ID variable*) and `X` (*a categorical variable not varying in `H`*) as represented by the `lme4` formula: `~ (1|H) + (1|X)`?

If yes, would that indicate that `H` and `X` are crossed random-effects even though NO value of `X` is capable of meeting every value of `H` as suggested by [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228814/140365)?

Finally, under nested random-effects, we say correlations exist among observations coming from the same cluster, but how do correlations come about under crossed random-effects as in my case?

```
H   X
1   2
1   2
2   1
2   1
2   1
3   2
4   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `(1|H) + (1|X)` would specify crossed random effects, when there is no nesting - you said that `X` doesn't vary within `H` and presumably the reverse is also true.

> Does this also mean each unique H cluster is correlated with another H cluster AND each unique X cluster is correlated with another X cluster?

I'm not sure if I've understood that question, but the correlation is between observations within each cluster (of each variable), not between them.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Three follow-up questions: **(1)** But here every value of `X` is NOT capable of meeting every value of `H` as suggested by linked answer for my random-effect to be crossed, so how come we still call `X` and `H` crossed? **(2)** (To clarify on what you said didn't understand) In nesting, we say correlations exist among observations coming from the same cluster, but how do correlations come about under crossed random-effects as in my case? **(3)** Under this random structure, neither `H` nor `X` can have an additional fixed effect in the model (`H + X + (1|H) + (1|X)`), correct?

Comment: You're welcome :) (1) that doesn't make sense to me. Random effects are crossed when they are not nested. (2) Correlation within clusters has nothing to do with nesting - it is to do with repeated measures or some kind of clustering. We can have 2 or more grouping variables that are not nested (ie they are crossed), and for each variable we will have an intra-class correlation. (3) There is nothing stopping you from fitting `H + X + (1|H) + (1|X)` but specifying a variable as both random and fixed makes almost no sense to me and I would recommend not doing it.

Comment: So, based on your answer to (2), I conclude that observations belonging to the same `H` cluster are correlated with each other and separately observations belonging to the same `X` are correlated with each other, right? Can we also confirm partial crossing by: `m = 
"H   X
1   2
1   2
2   1
2   1
2   1
3   2
4   1";
dat=read.table(text=m,header=T);
xtabs(~H+X,data = dat)` ?

Comment: They *might* be correlated. It's not certain, nor is it certain that the correlation would be higher enough to detect. As for confirming partial crossing - you can't know for sure because it depends on the study design and how the data are encoded.

Comment: Hi Robert, I think [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/539946/140365) is of interest to you. Thank you.